# Некорректное отображение символов в xlsx записанным openpyxl в браузере safari на iPad

Tags: python, safari, openpyxl

Доброго. Есть скрипт, который записывает некоторые данные в xlsx. И все было бы хорошо, если бы не нужно было бы открывать этот самый отчет на яблочном планшете, прямо в браузере, с веб-сервера.
Проблема заключается в том, что Сафари открывает строчки, записанные openpyxl, исключительно как ###
Если открыть файл на пк в Exel, затем сохранить файл и залить его на тот же веб-сервер откуда он скачан, файл отображается  в сафари нормально. 
UPD Разобрался немного. Браузер отображает желаемое форматирование как данные.
UPD2 Решил отказаться от использования column.number_format и форматировать заливкой ячеек цветом. Все работает.

```
import bs4 as bs
import urllib.request
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import datetime


def main():

    wb = load_workbook('file.xlsx')
    ws = wb.active
    maxrow = ws.max_row
    #Вычисляю дату анализа, дата отображается верно.
    date = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d -%a- %m.%y %H:%M")
    #Функции, необходимые для добычи еще одного значения(строка чисел, которую я сразу же перевожу в int), не корректно отображаются
    a_obj = get_count(get_xml('http://someurl.com'))
    a_obj = int(a_obj)


    ....

    ws.append({1:date, 2:all_obj, 3:d_all_obj, 4:a_obj, 5:d_a_obj, 6:n_obj, 7:d_n_obj, 8:u_obj, 9:d_u_obj, 10:kontr_a, 11:d_kontr_a})

    maxrow = ws.max_row
    j=2
    while j < 12:
        column = ws.cell(row=maxrow, column=j)
        column.number_format = '# ##0.00;[red]-# ##0.00'
        j += 1
    wb.save('file.xlsx')
```

Comment: Вроде как в вашем примере нет кода, который бы осуществлял заполнение ячеек данными.

Comment: ws.append же
Сейчас отредактирую код, добавлю присвоение страницы .

Comment: В той строчке только имена переменных, данных нет. Или все, что было записано, отображается как "###"?

Comment: Я для краткости опустил вычисление всех переменных. Да и за код стыдно.
Первая ячейка с датой отображается корректно. Остальные нет. Возможно проблема в том как я их вычисляю? Сейчас добавлю еще кода.

Comment: Что должно отображаться вместо `###`? Вы буквально символы ### (решётку) видите? Или это подстановка вместо  кракозяб? Попробуйте *минимальный, но самодостаточный* пример кода создать, который показывает проблему. [mcve] Если вы этот `xlsx` файл в Pages на iPad откроете, то что происходит? *"корректно сохранить веб-документ эксель файла на сервер."* — файл это набор байтов  — используйте любые средства для копирования файлов, чтобы закачать этот файл на сервер (например, `scp` если с терминала на сервер по ssh заходите).

Comment: Числа. Да, буквально решетку.  В Таблицах на iPad все адекватно видно.